# How to create a Collector that forms a special printable String in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to implement this method:

```java
public Collector<CourseResult, ?, String> printableStringCollector() {
```

which returns a `Collector` that forms a special printable `String` as described below.

It is multiline `String` containing a formatted table of all results and total values and marks.

A format of your table should meet the following requirements:

- Headers are required.
- Column width depends on values lengths.
- Rows are sorted by students' last names.
- Columns are sorted by the names of tasks.
- Double values displayed with 2 digits after the decimal point.
- Values of the column "Mark" are defined by average total score.
- Pay attention to alignment of different columns.

So far I write this code:

```java
public Collector<CourseResult, ?, String> printableStringCollector() {
    return Collector.of(

        StringBuilder::new,
        (sb, courseResult) -> {
            Person person = courseResult.getPerson();
            Map<String, Integer> taskResults = courseResult.getTaskResults();

            List<String> taskNames = taskResults.keySet().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

            // Calculate the total score and average mark
            int totalScore = taskResults.values().stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
            double averageMark = (double) totalScore / taskResults.size();
            // Append the formatted row to the StringBuilder
            sb.append(String.format("%-16s", person.getLastName() + " " + person.getFirstName()));
            for (String taskName : taskNames) {
                sb.append(String.format("|%-12s", taskResults.getOrDefault(taskName, 0)));
            }
            sb.append(String.format("|%-10.2f|%-5s|\n", averageMark, calculateMark(averageMark)));
        },

        // Combiner: Combine two StringBuilders by concatenating their contents
        (sb1, sb2) -> sb1.append(sb2.toString()),

        // Finisher: Return the final formatted table string
        StringBuilder::toString);
}

private String calculateMark(double avg) {
    return avg > 90 ? "A" 
        : avg >= 83 ? "B" 
            : avg >= 75 ? "C" 
                : avg >= 68 ? "D" 
                    : avg >= 60 ? "E" 
                        : "F";
}
```

How can I add a header with String "Student" and taskName?

Example:

```
Student........|Phalaxing |Shieldwalling |Tercioing |Wedging |Total |Mark |
Eco Betty......|0 ........|83............|89........|59......|57.75 |F ...|
Lodbrok Johnny |61 .......|92............|67........|0.......|55.00 |F....|
Paige Umberto..|75....... |94............|0.........|52......|55.25 |F....|
Average........|45.55.... |89.67.........|52.00.....|37.00...|56.00 |F....|
```

Comment: It's not clear where `Average | avr1 | ... | F` is supposed to go. Perhaps you could show the expected output for 2 students, with header, etc. Also, you could rewrite the averaging code as `double averageMark = taskResults.values().stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Integer::doubleValue));`

Comment: I added an example with the required output

Comment: Are you prevented from mapping `courseResult` items to a String (a single line in the body of the table), and sorting by student name prior to calling the collector? As it is now, you are hamstrung by the fact that your data is not really prepared for easy collecting.

Answer (score 0):

@Ksenia, In the 'Finisher' function, instead of this

```
        // Finisher: Return the final formatted table string
        StringBuilder::toString);
```

you can have any kind of logic implemented...

```
        // Finisher: Return the final formatted table string
        sb -> {
            StringBuilder headerRow = new StringBuilder();
            // Build the header in headerRow with proper column widths using keys and task names
            // E.g. Student........|Phalaxing |Shieldwalling |Tercioing |Wedging |Total |Mark |
            sb.insert(0, headerRow); // This inserts the header at the first position in the string builder
            // You may prepare the average row also similarly, and append at the end
            StringBuilder avgRow = new StringBuilder();
            // Build average row here
            sb.append(avgRow);
            return sb.toString();
        });
```

Also, since you have to format the strings properly, you have to first find the max length of all the columns.  So, you may have to traverse through the CourseResult twice. Once to get the max length out of all the names and task names to determine the lengths.
This should be done before `Collector.of()` is called.
So, in the `Combiner` and `Finisher`, those lengths are available already.